# Webbrowser control select radio button and click submit

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get my `WebBrowser` control to select a radio button and as well click a submit button which doesn't have any id or name.

Here is the html code from the web page:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="3" id="a3">
   <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="2" id="a2">
   <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="1" id="a1">
   <input value="Next" type="submit">
</form>
```

And here is the C# code I've tried:

```
wbv(3); //This part just check every 3 seconds to see if the page the page has loaded before continuing with the code
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("chosen")[2].InvokeMember("click");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByValue("Next")[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

I need help to figure out how to get my code to select the `radio` button with value 3 and then click the `submit` button.

Comment: and those errors are...?

Comment: @MarcB http://prntscr.com/cjzb66

Comment: The errors that you have shared in the screenshot are compile-time error and we cannot see the code which has such errors. Anyway for example, I've shared an answer showing you how you can click on a radio button and submit programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its quiet simple you were nearly there, you can drop this snippet within *DocumentCompleted* handler

*Note:* You cannot use *GetElementsByName* to trigger your *submit button* as it does not have a name attribute or an Id attribute

```
var radioClick = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("chosen").OfType<HtmlElement>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == "a2").FirstOrDefault()
            .InvokeMember("Click");

var buttonClick = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").OfType<HtmlElement>()
            .Where(html => html.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit") && html.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Next")).FirstOrDefault()
            .InvokeMember("Click");
```

> I'm trying to get my webbrowser1 to click/select a radio button and as
>   well click a submit button without any id or name.

*But your HTML seems to have an Id and Name, except for Button, nevertheless we can use GetAttribute("value") of the elements*

```
var radioBoxValue = "1";
var submitButtonValue = "Next";

//Click Radio Box
var findRadioBox = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").OfType<HtmlElement>()
                .Where(html => html.GetAttribute("type").Equals("radio") && html.GetAttribute("value").Equals(radioBoxValue)).FirstOrDefault();
findRadioBox.InvokeMember("Click");

//Click Button
var findsubmitButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").OfType<HtmlElement>()
                .Where(html => html.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit") && html.GetAttribute("value").Equals(submitButtonValue)).FirstOrDefault();
 findsubmitButton.InvokeMember("Click");

 //Unsubscribing from the document completed event, there are times when you will run into situations where documentcompelted will fire multiple times
 webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
```

**Full Snippet**

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string url = @"https://localhost:5001/Home/Index";
    webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=  webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

}

private async void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    var radioBoxValue = "1";
    var submitButtonValue = "Next";

    //Click Radio Box
    var findRadioBox = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").OfType<HtmlElement>()
                .Where(html => html.GetAttribute("type").Equals("radio") && html.GetAttribute("value").Equals(radioBoxValue)).FirstOrDefault();
    findRadioBox.InvokeMember("Click");

    //Click Button
     var findsubmitButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").OfType<HtmlElement>()
                .Where(html => html.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit") && html.GetAttribute("value").Equals(submitButtonValue)).FirstOrDefault();
    findsubmitButton.InvokeMember("Click");

    //Unsubscribing from the document completed event, there are times when you will run into situations where documentcompelted will fire multiple times
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;


}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind to explain how is it different from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60470038/3110834)?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps if you'd actually bothered READING those errors:

```
[..snip..] + version"&key="+ key. [..snip..]
                    ^---huh?
```

You're missing a `+` there.

Comment: And also another at the end, &key="+ key.Text"", could just drop the last quotes anyways not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your radio buttons have `id` attribute and you can chose find them using `GetElementById`. Also to get elements by name you can use `GetElementByName`.

But assuming you want to find an element based on some other criteria, for example based on `value` or `type` attribute, after you get a collection of elements by `Document.GetElementByTagName` or event by getting `Document.All`, to apply more filter you can cast the collection to `IEnumerable<HtmlElement>` using `Cast<HtmlElement>` and then use linq to filter the results.

You should try to find the element after the document completed, do you should usually put the code in `DocumentCompletet` event handler. In some cases, for example when the page loads using ajax requests you need to wait a bit, to let the page load.

**Example - Click on Radio Button and Submit**

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("the url or your page");
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (obj, args) =>
{
    var element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        .Cast<HtmlElement>()
        .Where(x => x.GetAttribute("value") == "2" &&
                    x.GetAttribute("name") == "chosen")
        .FirstOrDefault();
    element.InvokeMember("click");

    var submit = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        .Cast<HtmlElement>()
        .Where(x => x.GetAttribute("type") == "submit" &&
                    x.GetAttribute("value")=="Next")
        .FirstOrDefault();
        submit.InvokeMember("click");
};
```